# Overlay two images in PHP with the top one's opacity

Tags: php

I've seen tons of scripts for overlaying two images with the top one being a png and making it transparent... that is NOT what I'm looking for.  What I'm looking for is combining two images, and making the top one's opacity low so it is just seen over the background image.  Going for the same type of effect as the Facebook celebratepride effect made, just with a different image.

Thanks!

Comment: so basically a watermark?

Answer (score 2):

This will combine 2 images just like you are asking for.

```
    <?php
    // Create image instances
    $dest = @imagecreatefrompng('image1.png');
    $src = @imagecreatefrompng('image2.png');

    // Copy and merge
    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 500, 70);

    // Output and free from memory
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($dest);

    ?>
```

You can find out more about how this works from the link below. http://goo.gl/bZEFT9